# Pass template to another template as parameter

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 7 web app. I have got a few components. One of them is `card.component` which should be a container for others (not for all).

Card template body:

```
<div id="main-container" class="container">
  <mat-card id="login-card">
    <div id="form-container">
      // here I want to paste another components view as a parameter
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

The next one is `login.component`. This component should use `card.component` template as a container and put the form from another component as a content.

I want it works something like that (psedocode):

```
<app-card [my-html-param]="app-login-form"></app-card>
```

Now in above component I would like to pass view from `login-form.component`

How can I achieve such functionality?

Comment: It's called **content projection**, it's done through `ng-content`, and you can find tutorials onine, [such as this one](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `<ng-content>`, it will let you add some content inside **app-card** :

```
<app-card>
    <app-login-form></app-login-form>
</app-card>
```

Then, in your **login-form.component.html** you can include the lines inside **app-card** tags with `<ng-content>`.

Comment: `ng-content` is what I was looking for!